# Testing webpage behind Great Firewall of China

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, regression-testing, ie9, ie8

I have a challange to tackle.
We have webpage that will be used by Chinese customers, we need to make sure it works properly in China.
Have you ever tested webpage that should work in China? What was your approach?

I was thinking about using somekind of chinese docker hosting with Windows Server in it (Internet Explorer most used there) and connect to it usig RDP or VNC, what do you think guys?

Comment: Using a VPN seems like a good option. You should read this-https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/quickly-check-site-visible-great-firewall-china/

Comment: good advice thx!

Comment: this one is usefull alot http://viewdns.info/chinesefirewall/

Comment: also Im thinking about remote desktop and connect by RDP and test in manually

Answer (score 1):

if you wanted to test what the filtering was doing to your site then you would need to run some browsers in china. You could do this with a selenium grid hosted in china driving OSes in vm guests.

if you just wanted to check how your site works on degraded bandwidth you could use something like wanem to simulate various types of issues.
http://wanem.sourceforge.net/

Given that the Great Firewall of China (GFC) is continually changing it settings and none of them are published i would expect you would need to do this regularly to ensure you where up to date.

I would suggest you adopt a combination of these approaches dependant on resources available.

Something else to consider is that if you have a lot of chinese users then maybe you should host a chinese copy of the site in china.

Comment: yup, Im thinking about docker in china and connect via vnc to it and run tests from there using selenium hub.

Comment: From what I've seen there is different filtering between users and hosting in China and out of China. This won't just be a linear delay but differences in responses across ports or protocols.